# Why is Swift type-safe?

Tags: ruby, type-conversion, swift

As more-or-less a Ruby monoglot, this has never been clear to me... The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006573/why-do-i-need-to-specify-what-type-a-variable-is-in-a-class-in-swift) explain how type-safety functions in Swift (and generally, I am guessing), but doesn't answer 'why'? Surely there is some performance or security benefit, but what is it exactly? Or is the benefit purely the strictness of the value later on -- the developer has the benefit of knowing some function will definitely perform (`.each` on an Array, for instance) or when run.

What trade-offs am I unknowingly adopting when I do this in, say, Ruby

```
x = Float.new
x = 3
x = "a"
x = [a, "a", ['a'], {a: 'a'}]
```

versus what benefits am I receiving in it's equivalent in Swift:

```
var v: String
var x = 3
var y = "a"
var z = [
  a, 
  "a", 
  ['a'], 
  ['a': 'a']
]
```

?

Apologies if this is too basic or redundant -- I didn't find a similar question searching SO.

Comment: Kind of all of the above - type safety helps with catching errors during development or at compile time, protects against memory errors, since the size of a memory that a variable points to won't ever change, and lets the compiler do optimizations it couldn't do in a non-type-safe language, among other things. You could start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety

Comment: This isn't really a Swift question. Or a Ruby question. The tradeoffs of type-systems are discussed in many many articles on the web, as well as existing Stack Overflow questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125367/dynamic-type-languages-versus-static-type-languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type-Safety is not only helpful for run-time, but also for compile-time.
It can help sticking to certain rules, and making code more obvious.

Swift does still not check for types at run-time, but doing a check at compile-time will already help eliminating a lot of errors. In ObjC you could do something like this:

```
NSString *string = (NSString *)@123;
```

Does it throw an error? No. Does it make sense to warn the developer when compiling? Of course!

Type-safety can make sense in many ways, so let's look at some examples.

---

## Examples

*Beware, some of this is pseudo code*

Remember using `id` for every possible thing? Those days lie in the past!

Which one is more obvious?

```
var numbers: Array<Int> = [
    1, 2, 3, 4
]
```

or

```
NSArray *numbers = @[1, 2, 3, 4];
```

---

```
var fontAttributes: Dictionary<String, FontAttribute> = [
    Font.Weight : FontWeight.Bold,
    Font.Decoration : FontDecoration.None,
]
```

or

```
NSDictionary *fontAttributes = @{
    Font.Weight : FontWeight.Bold,
    Font.Decoration : FontDecoration.None,
}
```

---

```
var predicate = Predicate<Person>({ person in person.name == "John" })
```

or

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.name == %@", @"John"];
```